# How to resolve Warning: Missing argument 2 for ufwp_widget_text ()

Tags: warnings

I am using the edume theme of online courses and when making a purchase of a course from my website give the following error. How could it solve?

Warning: Missing argument 2 for ufwp_widget_text() in /home/basic340/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-udemy/includes/widgets.php on line 63

Warning: Missing argument 3 for ufwp_widget_text() in /home/basic340/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-udemy/includes/widgets.php on line 63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to `false` in your wp-config.php file. **This won't fix the problem** however It will only hide **ALL** the errors generated by it and any other plugins.

The warnings mean the second and third parameters in the `ufwp_widget_text()` function have no defaults set.

If you are using this function in your own code be sure to pass all three arguments.

If you are not, you will want to make sure the plugin is up to date; it's possible the error was already fixed by the developers. If the issues still persists you can reach out to the developers to report your issue report the issue on [the plugin's github repo](https://github.com/flowdee/wp-udemy/issues).